# HTML-Table: center by longest word

Tags: html, css

I have this in HTML.

```
<table style="width: 100%;" border=1>
<tr>
<td style="width: 33%;">left</td>
<td style="width: 33%; text-align: center;">mid<br>middle<br>middddle</td>
<td style="text-align: right;">right</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Looks like so

```
------------------------------------------
          |         mid       |      
left      |        middle     |      right     
          |       middddle    |
------------------------------------------
```

But I want this

```
------------------------------------------
          |       mid         |      
left      |       middle      |      right     
          |       middddle    |
------------------------------------------
```

How can I get there with CSS??

**EDIT:** added with checkbox instead of simple text

Solutions with justify-content works like a charm - but with a checkbox the 
 seems to be ignored. I replaced for example the checkbox with a string cause I did not expect to have it behave different - I was wrong.

```
<table style="width: 100%;" border=1>
<tr>
<td style="width: 33%;">left</td>
<td style="width: 33%;"><span style="display:flex; justify-content: center;"><input type="checkbox"/>mid<br><input type="checkbox"/>middle<br><input type="checkbox"/>middddle</span></td>
<td style="text-align: right;">right</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code will help you with your requirement.

```html
<table style="width: 100%;" border=1>
<tr>
<td style="width: 33%;">left</td>
<td style="width: 33%; text-align: center;">
<span style="text-align: left; display: inline-block;">mid<br>middle<br>middddle</span>
</td>
<td style="text-align: right;">right</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This does work with checkbox too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can assign to the middle td display:flex; and wrap your middle td content in a div container. Like that:

```css
.m-td {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.m-td div{
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%;" border=1>
<tr>
<td style="width: 33%;">left</td>
<td class="m-td">
  <div>
    mid<br>middle<br>middddle
  </div>
</td>
<td style="text-align: right;">right</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

#### Update

Thank you for hint @NikeshKp. For some reasons try to avoid use flexbox in the table.

> Don't use flex property on tables. If used on mailers it will not work
> in some email service providers like outlook.

Here the answer without flex.

```css
.m-td {
  text-align: center;
}

.m-td div{
  text-align: left; 
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%;" border=1>
<tr>
<td style="width: 33%;">left</td>
<td class="m-td">
  <div>
    mid<br>middle<br>middddle
  </div>
</td>
<td style="text-align: right;">right</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Don't use flex property on tables. If used on mailers it will not work in some email service providers like outlook.

Comment: @NikeshKp Can you provide a link where you found this information, please?

Comment: I came to know about this while working with HTM mailers.

Comment: @NikeshKp Can't there be another reason for this? flexbox isn't totally new now. Maybe only with older Outlook versions? A link or screenshot would be good!?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it like this. Hope that how you want it to look.

```html
<table style="width: 100%;" border=1>
<tr>
<td style="width: 33%;">left</td>
<td style="width: 33%;">
<span style="display:flex; justify-content:center">
mid<br>middle<br>middddle
</span>
</td>
<td style="text-align: right;">right</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Does not work with checkbox instead of simple text - I extended my sample above.